# Trying to access an index beyond the bounds of an array

Tags: cocoa

```
// Create the File Open Dialog class.
NSOpenPanel* openDlg = [NSOpenPanel openPanel];

// Enable the selection of files in the dialog.
[openDlg setCanChooseFiles:YES];

// Enable the selection of directories in the dialog.
[openDlg setCanChooseDirectories:YES];

// Display the dialog.  If the OK button was pressed,
// process the files.

if ( [openDlg runModalForDirectory:nil file:nil] == NSOKButton )
{
    // Get an array containing the full filenames of all
    // files and directories selected.
    NSArray* files = [openDlg filenames];
    NSString *string1;
    // Loop through all the files and process them.
    for( i = 0; i < [files count]; i++)
    {
        NSString* fileName = [files objectAtIndex:i];
        // Do something with the filename.
        string1 = [[NSString alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:fileName];
        if(string1 == nil)
        {
            NSLog(@"Error reading file");
        }
        else
        {

        }
    }
}
```

When i click on open button first time it will open open dialog box and woks fine
but when i clicked on open button second time it gives an error like

*** -[NSCFArray objectAtIndex:]: index (0) beyond bounds (0)

Comment: This code is in click event of nsbutton something like

Comment: Where is the `i` variable declared, and where else are you accessing the array?

Comment: On what line is the exception raised?

Comment: I don't think this will fix the problem, but you can use fast iteration: `for(NSString fileName in files)`

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if that will solve your issue, but runModalForDirectory is deprecated, consider using  [runModal](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSSavePanel_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSSavePanel/runModal) instead.